# trouble saving an object for unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have a problem saving an object (any object) for unit testing. For example, with the given object

```
@Mock([ConvertToDicomService, EventRouterService, User])
@Build([UploadedFile, Manifest])
@TestFor(EventRouterService)
class EventRouterServiceSpec extends ConstraintUnitSpec {
    def setup() {
    User.metaClass.encodePassword = {-> }
    List baseline = []

    User archer = new User( username: 'archerSterling', lastName: 'archer', firstName: 'sterling', accountExpired: 'false', accountLocked: 'false', password: 'password', emailAddress: 'a@gmail.com', externalId: 34)
    baseline.addAll([archer])
    baseline.each {
        println "saving: $it"
        if (!it.save(flush: true)) {
            println "\t... Failed"
        }
    }
}
```

the save method is called on the `user` controller

but the user controller uses another controller to handle all actions

```
import grails.rest.RestfulController

class UserController extends RestfulController<User> {
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    UserController() {
        super(User)
    }
}
```

which is supposed to execute the save method in RestfulController.groovy

```
/**
 * Saves a resource
 */
@Transactional
def save() {
    def instance = createResource(getParametersToBind())

    instance.validate()
    if (instance.hasErrors()) {
        respond instance.errors, view:'create' // STATUS CODE 422
        return
    }

    instance.save flush:true        
}
```

but, when I step-through in debug mode, the RestfulController.save() method never executes and I receive this error message

`groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: save for class: com.example.User
Possible solutions: all`

Admittingly, I am not all that familiar with this type of controller interaction, and need help figuring out possible solutions. Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Is this your real code? Why you called `it.save` instead of `archer.save`?

Comment: good eye, I shortened up the code quite a bit to help keep from cluttering the page. I edited in the actual code for the save method.

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing your controller you need to mock you domain class, as explained in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html):

### Test Mixin Basics

Most testing can be achieved via the TestFor annotation in combination with the Mock annotation for mocking collaborators. For example, to test a controller and associated domains you would define the following:

```
@TestFor(BookController)
@Mock([Book, Author, BookService])
```

So in your example:

```
@TestFor(UserController)
@Mock(User)
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {
}
```